# Web bridge between Java client to C# class library

Tags: java, .net, android, web-services, c#-3.0

I have an class library containing approximately 10 dll's written in C# 3.0/.NET 3.5. The library supply API access to my product running a remote server. Communication is done using TCP sockets.

I am looking for a way to write a client app for android/Linux in java. The problem is that the API
is pretty big and converting it from C# to java can take a lot of resources and time. Trying to avoid converting.

Anyone can think about a way achieving a working android client that uses the C# API without having to embed it into the client? 
Thought about getting a web service to do all the work against the core API and access it from java, the problem is that the TCP connection to the server has to be kept open at all time and a web service solution is stateless. Maybe a way to use a web service with persistent connection (is there such a thing?). Any creative ideas?

Comment: Could you expand as to why the TCP connection has to remain open at all times?

Answer (score 1):

Why does the tcp connection have to be open all the time? A webservice would be a nice solition because on the Java side you can generate the stubs/proxy classes and have virtually no work left.

Comment: It has to stay opened and keep the session alive. The API requires a Login and a persistent session. It's critical secured system. I am not sure how can I implement that using a web service. ideas?

Comment: I had the same question years ago and did not resolve it. However it is possible to resolve it, I am sure. Webservice can work over http which surely can be hacked to support a session cookie. Ask a new question, I know nothing about that. Consider doing a keep-alive dummy webservice call every 19min to keep the session alive.

Comment: I'm not sure a session cookie will be enough for the security demands the system has to answer to. This is why I am looking for a way to achieve a persistent TCP connection to the web server, or any other creative method for that matter.

Comment: Can you elaborate why the session cookie would not be enough? Maybe I can help you find an alternative. Btw, web services can surely operate on a persistent connection. If you can endure lots of pain, WCF is very customizable.

Comment: The product is working with corporations which define the security standard (can't really explain why cookies are a problem for them). I am not allowed to change the communication infrastructure. The API uses a persistent TCP connection and I am bound to keep this method of with any "new" wrapper I write on top of it.

Comment: I understand. I feel I cannot add further value to this question. But I think I have given usable hits regarding customizability of WCF.

Answer (score 0):

Here a creative idea: Implement a binary protocol over a persistent TCP connection that allows you to call any method inside of your server. For example the client might send:

{ class: 'BankService', method: 'StealMoney', parameters: { amount: 123 } }

And your server process would execute this using reflection.

Comment: Very nice idea... maybe pre-route the commands to the functions for performance but i like the idea. The only down side i can see here is that i cant give away this API because there are no objects or methods a developer can work with. thank you @usr

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it took so long to respond to this.  In non-Android scenarios, JNBridgePro (www.jnbridge.com) would be a good solution.  We've never had anyone run the Java side on Android, but we'd be happy to work with you to get that working.

Disclosure: I work for JNBridge.